# Is there any way to store the files locally on computer using react with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using electron and react hooks to make a game called risk. The game will a single player game. I want it to be like a normal desktop app which could run without internet or anything. A player can make his own maps and store in on the computer. I am unable to find any way to read and write files locally on computer using react?

I have seen some stackoverflow posts which says that without server its impossible to read and write data on clients system. If this is true then what is the simplest way to connect react app with node and write files. I thought of using `socket.io`. Will it work in this case.

Comment: If you enable node integration in electron, you will be able to use all Node modules and context in the renderer process, and should be able to use `fs` to read / write files

Comment: @Seblor any guide to how to integrate node in electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Node integration in electron, for exposing the Node context (and modules) to the renderer process, you can set the `nodeIntegration` property as `true` :

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  // All your other options
  "webPreferences": {
    "nodeIntegration": true
  }
});
```

Then, you can simply use the `fs` module to read and write files on the file system.

Documentation link : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

---

The other solution is to send IPC messages to send the maps from the renderer process to the main process (and vice-versa) and since the main process runs in the Node context, you can call the `fs` methods directly.

Comment: Already tried that. Its not working `require('fs')` gives empty object. `require('electron')` will error `fs.existsSync is not a function`

Comment: @MaheerAli what happens if you use `window.require` instead of `require` ?

Comment: `window.require is not a function`. Note:  I used [this](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3) to setup electron and react

Comment: @MaheerAli can you edit your question with your `BrowserWindow` creation ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this question. The code is working. The problem was that I didn't reloaded the electron again after setting `nodeIntegration` to `true`. Now its working thanks